# How can I make a Chrome Extension open an external page instead of the defualt popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know how can i make it possible so that when the extension's icon is clicked that it goes to a website, let's say http://stackoverflow, instead of opening popup.html. Is this possible? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Don't define a popup, since you won't need it.  Use

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback);
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked

The event won't fire if you defined a popup.  These will set no popup:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup:''});
```

Comment: This would go in my Manifest file? Or in my background.html file?

Comment: Ahh, Nevermind. I added it to my background.js. Thanks!